# Finding a specific pattern using regex in xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, xpath-1.0

I want to find a specific text using regex in a xpath.

This is my xpath:

```
locator: //*[@class = 'android.widget.TextView' and contains(@text,'PriceBottomBarDialog-selector')]
```

This "PriceBottomBarDialog-selector" remains constant, the beginning text keeps changing. Can anyone please help with the regex pattern?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You need to fix up the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) and you can use the [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Xpath:

  ```
  locator: //*[@class = 'android.widget.TextView' and contains(.,'PriceBottomBarDialog-selector')]
  ```

Comment: It is actually the content-desc "item-Jet item-PriceBottomBarDialog-selector". Any idea how to implement this. "PriceBottomBarDialog-selector" remains constant.

Comment: @Piku If I have understtod your question properly, incase it is `content-desc="item-Jet item-PriceBottomBarDialog-selector"` you can do `contains(@content-desc,'PriceBottomBarDialog-selector')`

Comment: Hi @DebsnjanB its not giving me the correct output, its giving me an error saying element not found.

Comment: @Piku This answer was to cater to your requirement of _regex pattern_. To address `element not found` can you raise a new question as per your new requirement?